# pandas: error saving Path object in parquet

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe, in that I have a column name `file_path` which is of type `Path`. I am trying to save that dataframe in `parquet` as below:

```
df # A dataframe stored in df
df.to_parquet(path='result.parquet', index=False)
```

But I am getting error as below:

```
"(\"Could not convert PosixPath(some_location_file_name.some_extenstion') with type PosixPath: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type\", 'Conversion failed for column file_path with type object')"
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: Solved. I applied `str()` to the column and then it saved successfully.